# Comparing array of force unwrapped optionals

Tags: swift

I'm writing a test:

```
    func test_arrayFromShufflingArray() {

        var videos = [MockObjects.mockVMVideo_1(), MockObjects.mockVMVideo_2(), MockObjects.mockVMVideo_3()]
        let tuple = ShuffleHelper.arrayFromShufflingArray(videos, currentIndex:1)

        var shuffledVideos = tuple.0
        let shuffleIndexMap = tuple.1


        // -- test order is different
        XCTAssert(videos != shuffledVideos, "test_arrayFromShufflingArray fail")
    }
```

But on the last line I get the last line:

```
Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to two '[VMVideo!]' operands
```

Comment: I wonder if this is a test target only thing. I've had issues with typing in our test target with cocoapods.

Comment: Does the VMVideo class conform to the Equatable protocol? Because it sounds like the compiler is telling you the objects in the array don't conform to it and is therefore unable to use the != operator on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays can be *compared* with `==` if the element type is `Equatable`:

```
/// Returns true if these arrays contain the same elements.
public func ==<Element : Equatable>(lhs: [Element], rhs: [Element]) -> Bool
```

But neither `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Wrapped>` nor `Optional<Wrapped>`  conform to `Equatable`, even if the
underlying type `Wrapped` does.

Possible options are (assuming that `VMVideo` conforms to `Equatable`):

- Change your code so that `videos` and `shuffledVideos` are
  `[VMVideo]` arrays instead of `[VMVideo!]`.
- Compare the arrays elementwise:

  ```
  XCTAssert(videos.count == shuffledVideos.count
      && !zip(videos, shuffledVideos).contains {$0 != $1 })
  ```
- Define a `==` operator for arrays of implicitly unwrapped equatable
  elements:

  ```
  func ==<Element : Equatable> (lhs: [Element!], rhs: [Element!]) -> Bool {
      return lhs.count == rhs.count && !zip(lhs, rhs).contains {$0 != $1 }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Swift can't tell how to compare two arrays to see if their contents are identical unless it knows how to compare individual elements. So you need to implement the `==` function on your class and adopt `Equatable`:

```
extension VMVideo: Equatable {
    // nothing goes here, == function has to be at global scope
}

func ==(lhs: VMVideo, rhs: VMVideo) -> Bool {
    // Up to you to determine what equality means for your object, e.g.:
    return lhs.essentialProperty1 == rhs.essentialProperty1 &&
        lhs.essentialProperty2 == rhs.essentialProperty2
}
```

**EDIT** To clarify how it interacts with `NSObject` and to troubleshoot your environment, please confirm the following:

```
class UnderstandsEqual: NSObject {}
let ok1: [UnderstandsEqual] = [UnderstandsEqual(), UnderstandsEqual()]
let ok2: [UnderstandsEqual] = [UnderstandsEqual(), UnderstandsEqual()]
ok1 == ok2 // no problem, evaluates to true

class DoesntUnderstand {}
let bad1: [DoesntUnderstand] = [DoesntUnderstand(), DoesntUnderstand()]
let bad2: [DoesntUnderstand] = [DoesntUnderstand(), DoesntUnderstand()]
bad1 == bad2 // produces a compile-time error
```

Comment: VMVideo is an obj-c class and we've overridden `isEqual`... Swift doesn't automatically use that I guess?

Comment: For ease I think I'll just convert them to NSArrays then.

Comment: Swift does. see page 457 of https://books.google.com/books?id=FMqhCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA457&lpg=PA457#v=onepage&q&f=false  So something is wrong. What happens if you try to do a plain compare using `==` of two VMVideo objects outside of an array?

Comment: let's me do `XCTAssert(videos[0] != shuffledVideos[0], "test_arrayFromShufflingArray fail")` without error

Comment: And how about the array compare in App code rather than testing code?

Comment: It looks like it is a test environment thing, a little out of my depth, but I'm curious if http://davidstechtips.com/2015/04/iskindofclass-and-xctest/ addresses your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Martin R's answer was the better answer, but for this specific purpose I just converted to NSArray's and was able to use the `==` operator in Swift:

```
func test_arrayFromShufflingArray() {

    let videos = [MockObjects.mockVMVideo_1(), MockObjects.mockVMVideo_2(), MockObjects.mockVMVideo_3()]
    let videosNSArray: NSArray =  videos.map { $0 }
    let tuple = ShuffleHelper.arrayFromShufflingArray(videos, currentIndex:1)

    let shuffledVideos = tuple.0
    let shuffledVideosNSArray: NSArray =  shuffledVideos.map { $0 }


    // -- test order is different
    XCTAssert(videosNSArray != shuffledVideosNSArray, "test_arrayFromShufflingArray fail")


    // -- test elements are the same
    let set = NSSet(array: videos)
    let shuffledSet = NSSet(array: shuffledVideos)
    XCTAssert(set == shuffledSet, "test_arrayFromShufflingArray fail")
}
```